# 404 not found, even though image exists

Tags: c#

Im loading images to a pictureBox with a link, one image works, but any other image after that won't work.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
  private void gameList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string imageLink = "https://web.xyz/storage/data/" + gameList.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace(" ", "%20").Replace("'", "%27") + ".png".Trim();
        pictureBox1.Load(imageLink);

    }
```

How this works is, the link will be found by matching the image filename to the listBox (gameList)'s name. IT WORKS, but only with the first one! The other ones give me a 404. If I check the string for "imageLink" it returns a working link, with every image.

I can load the NON WORKING image by using pictureBox1.Load("https://web.xyz/storage/data/image.png") perfectly.
What is the issue here?

Comment: What do you mean "gives you a 404" - what exactly do you see? What exactly does it tell you is the `imageLink` on the failed attempts? Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: Also view https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-5.0

Comment: This is the error I'm getting when I click on a value in a listBox other than the first one.
"System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'"
The image is 100% there.